# Is there a way to remote exec a shell script as a root user through Terraform on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, shell, terraform, remote-execution

I am doing following on Azure cloud using Terraform,

1. Create a RHEL OS VM on Azure.
2. Copy a setup.sh file to the new VM.
3. Using remote execution, I am running a setup.sh script as below.

   ```
   provisioner "remote-exec" {
   inline = [
   "chmod +x /home/${var.admin_username}/setup.sh",
   "sudo /home/${var.admin_username}/setup.sh",
   ]
   connection {
   type     = "ssh"
   user     = "${var.admin_username}"
   password = "${var.admin_password}"
   host     = "${azurerm_public_ip.tf-vm-pip.fqdn}"
   }
   }
   ```

Issue: The script to run on new VM needs root permissions for executing commands.

I have tried the following,

1. user     = "root" does not work, as we will not have root user password on Azure.
2. Tried sudo su/ sudo -i inside inline block.

   ```
   inline = [
   "chmod +x /home/${var.admin_username}/setup.sh",
   "echo "${var.admin_password}" | sudo -S su",
   "sudo /home/${var.admin_username}/setup.sh",
   ]
   ```
3. Modify shell script so that every command is executed as sudo like below,

   ```
   echo "password" | sudo -S -k cmd1
   echo "password" | sudo -S -k cmd2
   echo "password" | sudo -S -k cmd3....
   ```

The third solution works for most of the commands. But is not preferred due to security issues.

Is there a way to do a remote installation of script as root user through Terraform on Azure cloud?

Comment: You would need to disable password authentication on sudo for this to work any better than your third option. If you're just going to echo the password to sudo in your script then there's pretty much no reason to have the sudo password anyway.

Comment: Would cloud-init help you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/using-cloud-init Also available through the `custom_data` field in terraform https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html

Comment: Disabling password authentication for sudo is working for me.

Comment: The cloud-init option can be the right option. But in my case, it is restricted by the customer, so could not check it.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use Custom Script Extension which execute the script as root.
Please find below mention links for your reference.
http://hypernephelist.com/2019/06/25/azure-vm-custom-script-extensions-with-terraform.html